# How to write to a file with netcat? And set it to grow to a certain size and begin overwriting itself?

Tags: netcat, tee

I'm currently writing a program that prints to a Zebra printer. Because my office doesn't have a zebra printer, we print to a linux VM running netcat with `nc -k -l -p 9100 | tee labels.txt` so that we can view the output to the printer and verify correctness.

Unfortunately, this file gets pretty big and takes up a lot of space on the VM, especially because no one ever remembers to clear it.

Using `tee` seems to be a good option for writing to a file, but it isn't very featured in the way I'd desire. I'd like for the `label.txt` to only grow to a certain size (say 20 MB), at which point it begins overwriting itself. Or perhaps renames `label.txt` to `label.txt.1`, allowing label.txt to grow and then overwriting `label.txt.1`.

Is there any way to do this with `netcat`/`tee`? Or should I be looking at another program?

Comment: Several options are described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6708580/use-tee-or-equivalent-but-limit-max-file-size-or-rotate-to-new-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your question, there is no feature in either `netcat` or `tee` to achieve this.

Maybe you could write a cron job, which runs every minute and checks the size of the `label.txt`, and when it reaches 20MB, clears the first 10MB.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple steps to what you want.

First, you'll need to put `nc -k -l -p 9100 | tee labels.txt` into a script, and add a handler for `SIGHUP` to restart the command.

Next, you'll need to setup `logrotate` to, well, rotate the logs.